# COPY Postgres table to CSV output, paginated over n files using python

Tags: python, postgresql, psycopg2

Using psycopg2 to export Postgres data to CSV files (not all at once, 100 000 rows at a time). Currently using `LIMIT OFFSET` but obviously this is slow on a 100M row db. Any faster way to keep track of the offset each iteration?

`for i in (0, 100000000, 100000):
  "COPY 
  (SELECT * from users LIMIT %s OFFSET %s)
  TO STDOUT DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER;" 
    % (100000, i)`

Is the code run in a loop, incrementing `i`

Comment: are you asking if running in a loop is a good idea or how to do it, I am confused

Comment: It must be run in a loop - I need CSV files of 100k lines. The loop is slow now because of the `OFFSET LIMIT` pattern

Comment: it doesn't have to be a loop, but you could use some other distinguishing key to try and pull 100k at a time. you could also use multiprocessing and hit this at the same time

Comment: Besides being slow, it's unsafe. Without an ORDER BY there's no guarantee that the order is stable across the multiple SELECTs. Don't you have a primary key in this table?  It could be used for both sorting and paginating.

Comment: There are no writes during the loop - will that ensure the order is stable? No primary key for this table, as it would slow down bulk writes.

Answer (score 1):

Let me suggest you a different approach.

Copy the whole table and split it afterward. Something like:

```
COPY users TO STDOUT DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
```

And finally, from bash execute the split command (btw, you could call it inside your python script):

```
split -l 100000 --numeric-suffixes users.csv users_chunks_
```

It'll generate a couple of files called users_chunks_1, users_chunks_2, etc.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking about this as a last resort - I'm going to hit 5B rows and I don't think my HDD can take exporting the entire CSV.